# Connect from Windows 10 to Raspberry Pi Zero over USB

Tags: ssh, raspbian-jessie, pi-zero, pi-zero-w

I am trying to connect RPi Zero from Windows 10, Was following this tutorial https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/ethernet-gadget
For some reason laptop is not able to detect USB Ethernet/RNDIS Gadget, What drivers I need to install for this to work.

[image]

Comment: I haven't used MS Windows in many years... However, it seems there may be some configuration requirements when trying to get Windows 10 to work with RNDIS... [Any Plan for Windows 10 to fix the problem of RNDIS?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/c5b1b3c5-7ac6-4ae9-ae68-dd69c14dc7d8/any-plan-for-windows-10-to-fix-the-problem-of-rndis?forum=wdk)  ....... and the driver **inf** template [Remote NDIS INF Template](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/remote-ndis-inf-template)

Comment: https://www.factoryforward.com/pi-zero-w-headless-setup-windows10-rndis-driver-issue-resolved/

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 doesn't ship with the necessary RNDIS driver. You'll have to install it manually. See https://www.factoryforward.com/pi-zero-w-headless-setup-windows10-rndis-driver-issue-resolved/ for a guide.